# How to implement the below scenario to show the POPUP dialog based on Time and also append to Listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-dialog

[image]

Here is my code i implemented to show the popup dialog

```
   public class ExPopup extends Activity {

Dialog myDialog;
Button myButton;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    AlertDialog.Builder helpBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ExPopup.this);
    helpBuilder.setTitle("Pop Up");
    helpBuilder.setMessage("This is a Simple Pop Up 1");
    helpBuilder.setPositiveButton("Accept",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // Do nothing but close the dialog
        }
    });

    helpBuilder.setNegativeButton("Decline", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // Do nothing
        }
    });
    // Remember, create doesn't show the dialog
    final AlertDialog helpDialog = helpBuilder.create();
    WindowManager.LayoutParams wmlp = helpDialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
     wmlp.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
     wmlp.x = 70;   //x position
     wmlp.y = 70; 
    helpDialog.show();
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Timer tshow = new Timer();
    tshow.scheduleAtFixedRate(
            new TimerTask()
            {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            helpDialog.show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            },0,10000);
    final Handler handler1 = new Handler();
    Timer thide = new Timer();
    thide.scheduleAtFixedRate(
            new TimerTask()
            {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    handler1.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            helpDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                }
            },0,20000);
    AlertDialog.Builder infoBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ExPopup.this);
    infoBuilder.setTitle("Pop Up");
    infoBuilder.setMessage("This is a Simple Pop Up 2");
    infoBuilder.setPositiveButton("Accept",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // Do nothing but close the dialog
        }
    });

    infoBuilder.setNegativeButton("Decline", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // Do nothing
        }
    });

    // Remember, create doesn't show the dialog
    final AlertDialog infoDialog = infoBuilder.create();
    WindowManager.LayoutParams wmlp1 = helpDialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
     wmlp1.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
     wmlp1.x = -75;   //x position
     wmlp1.y = -25; 
    helpDialog.show();
    infoDialog.show();
    final Handler handler11 = new Handler();
    Timer tshow1 = new Timer();
    tshow1.scheduleAtFixedRate(
            new TimerTask()
            {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    handler11.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            infoDialog.show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            },0,10000);
    final Handler handler12 = new Handler();
    Timer thide1 = new Timer();
    thide1.scheduleAtFixedRate(
            new TimerTask()
            {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    handler12.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            infoDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                }
            },0,20000);
            }

             }
```

Here from above iam adding a popup based on time i mean for every 10 sec new popup is added and the old popup will come down so up on 2 to 3 added and old popups must be disappeared from the list ....So please help me in this scenario Thank you for your help .....

Comment: So you want a new dialog to show up every 10 seconds and the old one to disappear? Why are trying to show two dialogs at once?

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track:

1. Draw the four layout either linear or relative.
2. Set background to transparent
3. Make the popup2 to popup4 invisible.
4. Call thread after each 10 minutes and set the linear of relative layout to visible.
5. Use style to display animation for popup.
6. Run and you will have pop up displayed one after each 10 sec